# How to use relational operators in map type in cassandra?

Tags: dictionary, cassandra, relational

```
create table tbl_master_values (
dbid int primary key,
user_dbid int, reg_dbid int,
module_dbid int,
fields_value map<text,frozen<list<text>>>,
created_date timestamp,
modified_date timestamp);

CREATE INDEX idx_fields_value ON tbl_master_values (Entries(fields_value));
```

fields_value column contain this value:

```
{'287': ['28'], '288': [''], '289': [''], '291': ['33'], '295': [''],'309': ['214', '215']}
```

Now I want like this:

```
select * from tbl_master_values where fields_value['287'] > 20;
```

It's shows following error

> InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Only EQ relations
>   are supported on map entries"

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Only EQ relations are supported on map entries"

It's pretty clear. No you can't do range scan (e.g. inequality relation) with native Cassandra secondary index, it's just not possible.